# Finding a bound on a specific value of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\overline{D(0,1)}$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M,$ if $|z|=1$ and $Im(z) \geq 0$ and $|f(z)| \leq N, $ if $|z|=1$ and $Im(z) <0.$

Could anyone advise me how to prove $|f(0)|\leq \sqrt{MN} \ ?$

My attempt: WLOG, let $M>N >0.$ I am trying to define holomorphic $g$ in terms of $f, M, N$ so I can use Maximum Modulus principle.

Comment: Are you sure you meant $Im(z)>0$? The two conditions are virtually the same except two points...

Comment: Can you use the Cauchy integral formula directly? The estimate may be a little bit off, but I feel this should be the right way.

Comment: Tried to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Put $g(z)=f(z)f(-z)$ and show that $|g(z)|\leq MN$ on $|z|=1$.

Comment: @Daniel Fisher: Yes, thank you very much, I edit.